# Deploy Custom app with StreamBridge using SCDF UI

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-dataflow-ui

I have an external (cloud) system pushing data to my (on prem) app. For this, I have created an app that accept HTTP Post, perform payload validation and send to RMQ using StreamBridge. I am trying to deploy the app using SCDF UI but getting issue with RMQ connectivity (connection is denied). However, when I run the app (war), it works just fine (and gets connected to RMQ).

Question - can I (or should I) deploy my custom app (that uses StreamBrige) using SCDF UI? Is this a standard practice? Or should I keep my custom app outside SCDF stream?

Comment: The above issue has nothing to do with StreamBridge. You have some infrastructure problem during packaging, deployment, network configuration etc. We don't know as you are not sharing much other than stating that you have a problem.

Comment: Oleg, you're right. I resolved the issue by manually passing RMQ details to StreamBridge application.